# Why does Unity increase the size of image when I use the image in Unity?

Tags: 2d, game-design, unity

I try to make a game in Unity 2d. But when I drop the image in Unity the image size increases 3 or 4 times. Can I fix that or is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default sprite size in Unity is 100 pixels per unit.

This means that if you have a sprite that is 100 pixels wide, it would occupy "1" Unity unit.  If you moved this sprite to the left by 1 unit, it would shift 100 pixels to the left.

You can change this value by selecting your sprite, and changing its "Pixels per Unit" property.

I typically set my sprites to their native size, for example, if a sprite is 64x64, I set it to 64 pixels per units.

Comment: Ok! So why the images deteriorated after when i compress them?

Comment: @Dr.iRi Unity also runs compression algorithms on the images, to try to reduce their size.  You can set your images to TrueColor, which is possibly what you are referring to.   There is also anti-aliasing that can cause issues depending on the graphic.    You can turn off anti-aliasing by setting your sprite's Filter Mode to Point Clamp.